# How to propertly set an image as border

Tags: html, css, border-image

I'm new to HTML and CSS, my task is to set an already prepared image as border.

What I'm doing wrong?

```css
div {
  width: 240px;
  height: 510px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/TqBJP5d/border-1.png) stretch;
}
```

```html
<div>
    123
</div>
```

Comment: Could you put up an image of what the final result should be. Also I can’t find the image you have given in your code, could you check that it is visible to us?

Answer (score 1):

More info [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp)

**Working example with your code**:

```css
   .bordered-box {
  width: 140px;
  height: 510px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 34px solid transparent;
  border-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/TqBJP5d/border-1.png) stretch 38;
  border-image-outset: 18px 19px 10px 12px;
  margin: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="bordered-box">
    123
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yea, but when i do it with my image it doesn't work :(

Comment: @ImAlex2000 i just update answer

Comment: I want the result to be like this: https://i.ibb.co/WySDpZy/border-1-1.png is there any way to do that?

Comment: @ImAlex2000 just check edit answer

Comment: Can't see, hmm... My goal is to set a purple border outside the blue box

Comment: @ImAlex2000 done, please check result

Answer (score 0):

you need a width value before the strech property

```
 border-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/TqBJP5d/border-1.png) 30 stretch;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Border width on your div with transparency.

```css
div {
  width: 240px;
  height: 510px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 39px solid transparent;
  border-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/TqBJP5d/border-1.png) stretch 38;
 
}
```

```html
<div>
123
</div>
```